# Why is connect-src Content-Security-Policy ignored by browser

Tags: javascript, browser, content-security-policy

I'm working on a React application that needs to fetch some data from another domain. As expected I'm getting CSP errors when trying to fetch data from that domain. By setting the CSP header to `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'self';` I was expecting that the connection would be reported but still allowed. However, I'm getting

*Refused to connect to 'https://mydomain' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

For other policy violations (e.g. styles) I'm getting *[Report Only] Refused to apply style...* (as expected)

I have the same behaviour when setting the header to `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://mydomain;` - the connection is blocked and the error is *Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set*. Why does it say it is not set when it is set and how to get it working? I'm using Chrome 86.

Comment: Looks like you app by default does publish the other CSP, not one that you are edit. Or you publish 2 CSPs at the same time (typical issue: one is delivered via header the second with meta-tag), in this case more restrictive CSP will acts. Check in the Dev Tool what CSP you have really got from server.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@granty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12865944/granty), I had the CSP delivered both via headers and  tag. The tag seems override the headers. There was some overlap in both policies, so it was giving an impression that CSP headers worked in some cases.
I'm going to stick with header-based approach as that can be easily customized via server configuration, e.g. between dev and prod environments.